# How to use \b or ^ alongwith pattern to replace complete word?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex for replacement of words, but instead of complete words even words in between sentences are getting replaced.

```
prepos = ['has','had','have','is','you']
prepo = re.compile('|'.join(prepos))

# x["text"] - contains text with sentences in english

twete = re.sub(prepo,' ',x["text"])
print(twete)
```

output: replaces subwords as well i want to subsitute complete word ocurrences only. How can I use `^` or `\b` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"\b(foo|bar|baz)\b")
p.sub("---", "foo XfooX bar YbarY baz ZbazZ")
# => '--- XfooX --- YbarY --- ZbazZ'
```

**Edit:**

If you want to join the regex:

```
prepos = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
p = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(prepos) + r")\b")
p.sub("---", "foo XfooX bar YbarY baz ZbazZ")
# => '--- XfooX --- YbarY --- ZbazZ'
```

Comment: i have a long list of prepositions adding them manually and editing using \b  will take a lot of time , thought about this before thanks for help . Can we use ^ or \b with pattern variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave the answer yourself.

Use \b to match the empty string at the beginning or the end of the word. Also, you must add braces around the groups to make sure that the whole group is matched. I also suggest using raw strings. Something like this should do the trick:

```
prepos = [r'(\bhas\b)',r'(\bhad\b)',r'(\bhave\b)',r'(\bis\b)',r'(\byou\b)']
prepo = re.compile('|'.join(prepos))

twete = re.sub(prepo,'-',' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
print twete
```